# How to correctly configure Sublime Text's "Expand Selection to Tag" command?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, sublime-text-2

I've been using Sublime Text for quite some time (both on OS X and Windows) and it's been working great. One of the features I like and use the most is "Expand Selection to Tag". On the Windows and OS X version, I put my cursor inside two HTML tags, and press the hotkey (ctrl+shift+a or cmd+shift+a) and it does this:

[image: On Windows / OS X]

Instead, when I try to do the same thing with that hotkey on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04), it does this:

[image: On Ubuntu 12.04]

Yet, the menu says that's the correct hotkey, but it's definitely not the right command.

When browsing the "Key Bindings - Default" preferences file, it's correctly bound:

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+a"], "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "tag"} },`

Yet it doesn't do what it's supposed to.

What's that command it's excecuting and how do I do to make that binding to do what's supposed to do?

Comment: Have you checked the `Default (Linux).sublime-keymap` file?

Comment: @Sara Where can I check that? I tried the home folder and I didn't find it. In the Pristine Packages folder (where ST2 is installed), the file's empty (inside the User.sublime-package file)

Comment: @Sara Is it in the root install folder? There's no such `packages` folder there :/

Comment: For me (OS X) it's in `Application Support` -> `Sublime Text 2` -> `Packages` -> `User` - I'm not sure what the Linux installation looks like, but presumably it's a similar structure? I also have `Pristine Packages` next to `Packages`.

Comment: Yup, I see that on OSX, but I don't see it in Ubuntu (that's why I stated that I searched the home folder, but nothing, since there's the place that user preferences usually go). It should be there, but it isn't.

Comment: Weird. What happens if you create that file and duplicate the key binding in there?

Comment: "Expand selection to tag" works for me (Ubuntu 12.04).  You can find the key bindings file by using sublime text: `Preferences > Key Bindings - User`.  The file is located at ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User (.config is hidden by default so you might need to enable display of hidden folders.

Comment: Do you have zencoding installed or something else taking over those hotkeys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @d_rail pointed out, there was a conflict with a Package ― in specific, Zen Coding.

When I uninstalled the package, it started working again as it should have from the beggining. I will proceed to reinstall the package and configure the key bindings so they won't collide.

How could I not see that before!?

Comment: I couldn't figure what was going on, then I saw the answer to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/489879/edit-both-opening-and-closing-html-tag and then it clicked.  Unfortunately, your predicament happens to me a lot, I install a bunch of plugins that look cool, then when something weird happens, I have no idea what is causing it.

Comment: Exactly what happened to me, and the link (and the comment inside the answer) describes exactly what happened.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve encountered such problems many times, but not anymore. Some enlightened person made a package to find key conflicts between packages: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/FindKeyConflicts