# Edit both opening and closing html tag

Tags: sublime-text-2

Is there a way (core or plugin) that a closing html tag name changes accordingly when renaming the opening one ? A behaviour similar to multi-selection...

Comment: Are you looking for a way to change it, or is it happening you you and you don't know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Zen coding](https://github.com/sublimator/ZenCoding) plugin has a command "select matching tag name" which selects the nearest opening and closing tags relative to the cursor.

Answer (score 22):

The ZenCoding plugin has been discontinued, see the alternative: [Emmet](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime)

```
(Super) + Shift + K // Rename tag shortcut
```

Also available via Package Control, under the same name.

Comment: This seems have been changed to Super + Shift + K for OS X (see: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/284305ed088633218aad663f0ccddbd1f5e6215b/Default%20(OSX).sublime-keymap#L286)

Comment: Thanks for the solution chibicode, you should enter it as such.

Comment: edited answer with the correct shortcut

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Emmet plugin](http://emmet.io/download/) shortcut key to rename tag in your editor:

```
[Super + Shift + K] on mac //In OSX environment, super key = Command key.
[Ctrl + Shift + '] on windows
```

It worked perfectly I already tested with sublime text

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this `command` to userKeyBindings:

> {"keys": ["your key bind.."], "command": "rename_tag"} // like super+shift+k